# How can I set GlobalizationSection.Culture on page load?

Tags: .net

I have a web page that I want to display dates on, dynamic to the culture code the user has defined.

I can set my web.config up like below to achieve what I want:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="fr-CA"/>
</system.web>
```

However, I want this to be user defined, so when they log in it automatically changes.

Any Idea how I can do this?